# How can I convert MINC files to Nifti format recursively in bash using "mnc2nii"?

Tags: bash, type-conversion, imaging

I need to convert image files with the MINC format (.mnc) to the NIfTI-1 format (.nii). 
I want to use the command "mnc2nii" of the minc-tools in Ubuntu bash.

"mnc2nii" requires an input (filename.mnc) and an output (filename.nii).

I have multiple folders and subfolders with MINC files in them.

I am trying to find a way to recursively convert all .mnc files to .nii so that they keep their name and folder structure.

Example:

file abc in /folder/abc.mnc converted to /folder/abc.nii

and

file xyz in /folder/subfolder/xyz.mnc converted to /folder/subfolder/xyz.nii.

Thank you

Comment: bravo for GNU-Parallel` solution, but also search here for `[bash] for loop`. There will be many answers that address essentially the same problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested because it's late here in the UK, so make a backup and test on a copy of a small subset of pictures.

First install **GNU Parallel**, then in terminal run:

```
find /path/to/mnc/files -type f -name \*.mnc -print0 |
   parallel --dry-run -0 mnc2nii {} {.}.nii
```

If you like the look, run it again without the `--dry-run`.

Being **GNU Parallel** it will do them very fast, in parallel :-)

Comment: Thank you four your answer!

The dry run looked good. Unfortunately, when I perform the command without it I get following error:

Can't find input file '/mnt/e/folder/subfolder/abc.mnc'
Can't find input file '/mnt/e/folder/subfolder/xyz.mnc' and so on.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `mnc2nii` on your PATH? I mean what happens if you type `which mnc2nii`?

Comment: Did you cut and paste my code, or copy it by hand? The parameter after `--dry-run` is dash-zero, not dash-letter O.

Comment: Please try running `mnc2nii /mnt/e/folder/subfolder/abc.mnc /tmp/junk.nii` and click `edit` under your question and paste output/result.

Comment: Running "which mnc2nii" produces "/usr/local/freesurfer/mni/bin/mnc2nii".

I cut and paste the code by hand.

When I run "mnc2nii /mnt/e/folder/subfolder/abc.mnc /tmp/junk.nii" I somehow get the same error: "Can't find input file /mnt/e/folder/subfolder/abc.mnc"

Thank you for your help!